# element reappears immediately after fadeOut()

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I'm trying to fade out some buttons after they're clicked but they immediately reappear. This is in Phonegap 2.7 on Android 4.2. In Windows Chrome, the element stay hidden after they fade out. Can someone help me? I can post a video of the behavior if that would help explain things.

**HTML**

```
<div id='button-div' class='row'>
    <div id='yes-outer' class='col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1'>
        <div class='button'>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i>
            <span>Yes</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='no-outer' class='col-xs-5'>
        <div class='button'>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
            <span>No</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.button').unbind('click').bind('click',function() {
    $('#button-div').fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is the page refreshing?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! It doesn't appear to be refreshing since the rest of the elements remain as they are.

Comment: raina77ow, can you elaborate on what the hover style would do in this case?

Comment: Is there more code that what is there....is there code that causes it to appear?

Comment: There is more code, but none of it applies to these elements.

Comment: What's confusing is that it works as expected in Windows Chrome and only reappears in Android webview.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/og8x2tcd/

Comment: Yeah, it only seems to happen on my phone. It even works correctly on my Nexus 7 tablet. http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/humor/misc/computer_grief.htm

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.button')[0].onclick=function() {
    $('#button-div').fadeOut();
}
```

You might add another function for fadeIn() and onClick. Both of them call immediately and cause that problem. In this method, you remove the functions list and replace it with that function.